# tfs 2013 - TF229003 adding sharepoint site to existint team project

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013

I am following this website "http://nakedalm.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2013/" to configure sharepoint 2013 with tfs 2013 (both are on different servers). I am stuck where when i try to configure a sharepoint site with an existing team project. 
[image]

Comment: Does that SharePoint site exist?

Comment: yes it does. i have added comment in your answer below

Answer (score 0):

If the SharePoint site for LADS does not currently exist you need to create it.

You can use the tfpt addsharepointportal command from the TFS power tools to create the SharePoint site first. You can also just create a Team Site at that location and map it to the Team Project.

Once you have mapped the Team Project to the site you can go and enable the TFS SharePoint feature in Site Settings that corresponds to your process template.

Comment: the site already exists and i was trying to link it with the team project. i also used the TFS Power tools (add projectportal command) and received this error: Unexpected error occurred.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected error occurred when Visual Studio tried to load Team Foundation Server client application.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CommandLine.TeamProjectCreator.CreateProject()